# Is it possible to view character statistics outside the game?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I sometimes want to check up on a World of Warcraft character statistic. For example, right now I'm wondering how many times one of my characters has died. up until recently, I'd check that by going to my armory, but the problem is that the armory has recently changed and they removed the statistics list.

Is there a way for me to see these statistics outside the game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Statistics page has been removed from the armory, but as Chris suggested, you can still get this information from the API. Specifically, head over to the API documentation (currently dev.battle.net/io-docs).

Under **Charcter Profile API**, you will see a `GET` method called "Statistics" that takes parameters in the form of `/WOW/CHARACTER/:REALM/:CHARACTERNAME`., each of these parameters being strings.

To access your character's statistics, you'll need to replace `:REALM` with the realm your character is on, and `:CHARACTERNAME` with your character's name.

You will need to put your locale and api key in the request URI. For example:

If I wanted to get the information for my character on kilrogg, mokov, I would use the URI: `https://us.api.battle.net/wow/charcter/kilrogg/mokov?fields=statistics&locale=en_US&apikey=YOURAPIKEY`.

This will return a JsonP callback, so if you do this in a tool such as [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) you can easily find the statistic you're looking for by simply checking that JSON key.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, they did remove the statistics page. I don't believe anybody actually knows *why*, but you can still access them through the API if you're interested.